# Managed identity authentication to Azure SQL fails from a container app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-container-apps

I'm using Azure Container Apps to run my .NET 8 application.
It's running with a user-assigned managed identity.
From the application, I'm trying to connect to a database in Azure SQL which is deployed to the same resource group.

I created a role assignment (Contributor, also tried Owner) for the managed identity in Azure SQL. Also, I allowed for Azure SQL to be accessed by Azure services. On the database level, I created a user for the managed identity as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql.
The connection string is set to something like `Data Source=<AZURE-SQL-SERVERNAME>; Initial Catalog=<DATABASE>; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; Encrypt=True;`

After deploying the application to Azure, I face the following errors in the container logs:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.

at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage)
at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.AcquireTokenAsync(SqlAuthenticationParameters parameters)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.<>c__DisplayClass147_1.<<GetFedAuthToken>b__1>d.MoveNext()
```

How can I fix this?
I don't want to enable SQL authentication with username/password.
I also tried to use a system-assigned identity but I got the same errors.